# algolia: algoliasearch has no call signatures

Tags: algolia

I'm using typescript. Ionic 4. Firebase firestore. Not anuglarfire.

my algoliasearch is throwing me an error. This is my first time using ionic.
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof . has no call signatures.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';


admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();



const algoliaClient = Here---> algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.appid, functions.config().algolia.apikey);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just found the solution here: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/error-ts2349-this-expression-is-not-callable/9905

Summary: Just replace `import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch'` with `import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch'`.

Comment: This worked for me after installing the '@types/algoliasearch' package. I also had some issues with an underlying version mismatch of '@types/algoliasearch-helper' which I removed to get this working. This post helped me solve the issues https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/issues/666